# Tag disambugation for [page-caching]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Today I retagged one question with [page-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/page-caching) tag, but then I noticed that it is used in two contexts:

- [Page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) which is disk data caching mechanism in Unix-like systems (that is what I meant)
- Caching of web-pages (most questions are regarding this topic).

Probably tag should be renamed (or deleted, it doesn't have wiki yet), but how questions should be retagged? At least questions regarding Unix subsystem should be named as **page-cache**, but this still leaves room for misunderstanding.